# There's something wrong with my Insertion Sort code

Tags: c++, insertion-sort

I learnt this implementation from mycodeschool, the method seems okay to me because that is how the instructor there teaches and I did the same implementation but somehow my code is giving an issue, also, please just ignore the time function because the error is somewhere else. I removed it and the error is still the same.

```
 //insertion sort
    #include<iostream>
    #include <ctime>
    using namespace std;
    class insertion{
    public:
        insertion(){} //constructor
        void sort(int a[], int n) { //insertion sort function
            for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
                int value = a[i];
                int index = i;
                while (i > 0 && a[i - 1] > value) {
                    a[index] = a[index - 1];
                    index=index-1;
                }
                a[index] = value;
            }
        }

        //display function
        void display(int a[], int n) {
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                cout << a[i] << endl;
            }
        }
    };
    void main(){
        insertion ins;
        int a[10];
        int n = 10;
        cout << "Enter the elements:" << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            cin >> a[i];
        }
        unsigned int start = clock(); //measuring time of sort from here
        cout << "waiting for keyhit";
        cin.ignore();
        ins.sort(a, n);
        ins.display(a, n);
        cout << "Time taken in millisecs: " << clock() - start; //to here
        cin.ignore();
    }
```

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: I see the swapping is not done properly in your case.

Comment: "Giving an issue"... you could at least be specific about what the problem is.

Comment: You may want to elaborate the question by adding what type of error you receive, and perhaps by changing the title into something more descriptive. (I believe it is SIGSEGV, but for us to help solve your issue, we should not be guessing the error you are facing)

Answer (score 1):

One mistake I could see is your incorrect usage of i in your while loop's termination condition. You should use the variable index instead, which I believe was your original intention, too.

After the correction I described, your sort function seems to work, as you may observe [here](http://ideone.com/yEEuLs), with a different main(). Below, you may see the definition of sort function *after* that correction.

```
void sort(int a[], int n) { //insertion sort function
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        int value = a[i];
        int index = i;
        while (index > 0 && a[index - 1] > value) {
            a[index] = a[index - 1];
            index=index-1;
        }
        a[index] = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you sooooooo much, I  realized my mistake, it was a blunder, stay blessed :')

Comment: @Mishaal You're welcome. Still, try to update your question statement in the direction people (including myself) recommended you do. Other people may face similar errors in the future and they should be able to find relevant posts in an easy manner. Currently your question contains vague statements and unclear points as to what your original problem was.

Comment: @Mishaal Also, if you are satisfied with one of the responses provided, do not forget to close your question by selecting the one that is the most satisfying as the answer to your question.